# JSP org.apache.tomcat cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I am new to Tomcat Project, to start the setup i duplicated a set of project from my friend there.
When i started the project, the index.jsp.java in the Tomcat work folder there is getting some error on the

```
  private org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager _jsp_instancemanager;

  public java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long> getDependants() {
    return _jspx_dependants;
  }

  public void _jspInit() {
    _el_expressionfactory = _jspxFactory.getJspApplicationContext(getServletConfig().getServletContext()).getExpressionFactory();
    _jsp_instancemanager = org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(getServletConfig());
  }
```

eclipse show "org.apache.tomcat cannot be resolved to a type" and "InstanceManager cannot be resolved to a type"

Any help on this issue?

Comment: Are you deploying your app directly into the tomcat or using Eclipse? If not using eclipse make sure you have setup you tomcat properly by setting CATALINA_HOME, JAVA_HOME etc (this is just a guess).. provide more info

Comment: Hi @ppuskar, i am using eclipse to deploy the project and have set the Windows>Preferences>Tomcat to Server.xml

Comment: Is InstanceManager supposed to be on the project's Java Build Path? The message is telling you it's not.

Comment: Sorry, I also don't know, the index.jsp.java is generated into the work folder, when i debug it show the red underline on it and debug line jump to other page.